# Самомодифицирующийся код на Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Код

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    void *p = &&modify;

    modify:
    // Перезаписать цифру пять нулем, 18 - это смещение от текущего адреса
    *(unsigned int *)((unsigned int)p + 18) = 5;
    printf("This is five = %d\n", 0);
}
```

должен сам себя менять.

Собирается бинарий

```
gcc selfmodify.c -o selfmodify
```

и снимается запрет на запись на секцию .text

```
objcopy --set-section-flags .text=alloc,code ./selfmodify
```

В итоге все падает с ошибкой сегментации в момент перезаписи нуля пятеркой.

У меня возник вопрос, а Linux реально разрешает переписывать свою секцию .text, если в ELF файле снят запрет на запись?

Comment: Вам не кажется, что писать самомодифицирующийся код под C/C++ - это моветон? Нельзя предсказать, какой именно код создаст компилятор для написанного вами кода.
К сожалению, я не могу ответить на ваш вопрос, однако посоветовал бы для изучения самомодифицирующегося кода уделить внимание ассемблеру.

Comment: Для справки: самомодифицирующийся код можно писать, на любом языке. Ссылка по теме (абзац Usages) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code

Comment: Вообще странно. Самомодифицирующийся код на линуксе всегда работал из коробки - благо исполнение на стеке всегда было разрешено.

Answer (score 5):

Линукс позволяет переписывать свою секцию .text, если флаг, запрещающий запись, снимается во время исполнения с помощью системного вызова mprotect. Еще надо иметь в виду, что на некоторых процессорах, например, семейства ARM необходимо сбросить кэш, чтобы процессор выполнил именно заново прописанные инструкции вместо закэшированных.

Answer (score -1):

Так вы модифицируете область памяти, а не исполняемый файл. Linux не следит за тем что вы делаете с ней. Так что всё должно работать. Надеюсь вы это в академических целях используете :-)

Comment: Не должно. Права доступа к страницам ещё никто не отменял.